# Алгоритм приведения массива в другой формат

Tags: php, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста из этого массива:

```
           Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [param1] => 2
                            [param2] => Значение2
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [param1] => 3
                            [param3] => Значение3
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [param1] => 2
                            [param4] => Значение4
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [param1] => 3
                            [param5] => Значение5
                        )

                )
```

Получить такой:

```
           Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [param1] => 2
                            [param2] => Значение2
                            [param4] => Значение4
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [param1] => 3
                            [param3] => Значение3
                            [param5] => Значение5
                        )
                )
```

Имена ключей всегда числовые и не упорядоченные по порядку, но всегда возрастают.

Всегда есть пара (и только пара) с одинаковым значением `param1`.

Количество таких пар не ограниченно

Comment: А массивы откуда, не из базы случайно ? я к тому, может на sql сделать, если это так

Comment: @Mike - может и на SQL можно, но уже по-моему проще лишнюю функцию написать). Просто архитектура базы совершенно иная и эта задача уже последней встала. До этого результата исходный массив уже побывал в мясорубке из трех вложенных циклов.

Comment: @dDevil пишите, пожалуйста, комментарии по существу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто пройдитесь по массиву и заполните соответствующую структуру

```
public function extractStructure(array $source) {
    $structure = [];
    foreach ($source as $values) {
        $id = $values['param1'];
        if (!isset($structure[$id])) {
            $structure[$id] = [];
        }
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $structure[$id][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $structure;
}
```